# cannot be cast to org.bson.BSONObject

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-collection

I try to make this program but I get this error

> cannot be cast to org.bson.BSONObject

I don't know if the structure of the program is fine. I want to do a program to search in the database (mongoDB) and print me all the events, but when I have a `pageLoad` event I want to check if it has a URL and to print it, else it should search again for the next event until again one event of `pageLoad`. So one loop like this.
The result it have to be like this for example.

- mouseMove
- mouseMove
- mouseMove
- click
- scroll
- click
- pageLoad....//htttp://www......url(1).....e.x
- mouseMove
- click
- pageLoad....//htttp://www......url(2).....e.x

---

```
MongoClient mongoClient;
DB db;

mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
db = mongoClient.getDB("behaviourDB_areas");

DBCollection cEvent = db.getCollection("event");
BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject();
orderBy.put("timeStamp", 1);
DBCursor cursorEvents = null;
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.put("user_id", "55b20db905f333defea9827f");
cursorEvents = cEvent.find(searchQuery).sort(orderBy);

if (cursorEvents.hasNext()) {

  while ((((BSONObject) db.getCollection("event")).get("type") != "pageLoad")) {

    System.out.println(cursorEvents.next().get("type").toString());


    if (((BSONObject) db.getCollection("event")).get("type") == "pageLoad") {

      System.out.println(cursorEvents.next().get("url").toString());

    }
  }
}
mongoClient.close();
}
}
```

Comment: `while((((BSONObject) db.getCollection("event")).get("type") != "pageLoad"))` looks wrong.  You can't cast `DBCollection` to `BSONObject`.  Surely you should be looking at the actual cursor event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through the results of your query using the cursor, use the following code:

```
while (cursorEvents.hasNext()) {
    DBObject documentInEventCollection = cursorEvents.next();
    // do stuff with documentInEventCollection
}
```

Further more, don't try to compare `String`s with `==` or `!=`. That won't compare the actual string but the object reference. If you want to check if the `type` field of a document equals the string `pageLoad`, use the following code:

```
if ("pageLoad".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type")) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```